# How to create a folder in /data/data/ in non-root mode

Tags: android, c++, apk, file-permissions

I encounter a serious problem, seems android can't handle a very long named apk and create a folder in non-root mode.
I have an debug-able apk has a name more than 100 chars. Firstly, I run it in root device, the process name(getting from command ps) is truncated to 86 chars.
 I run command `"mkdir -p /data/data/<86 chars process name>/files"` to create a folder and it succeeded in root mode.
 then I switch to test on non-root devices, I run command `"run-as <86 chars process name> mkdir -p /data/data/<86 chars process name>/files"` it reports

> Package <86 chars process name> is unknown.

then I tried `"run-as <more than 100 chars process name> mkdir -p /data/data/<86 chars process name>/files"` it still failed in creating folder and reports

> "Package  has corrupt installation".

my apk did have permission of write external.

can anyone help?

Comment: Um, why isn't your app just creating this directory itself, by using `getFilesDir()`?

Comment: actually, my app is a c++ app and also, our app is designed to intercept other app's api call as an interposer. so we have to run command outside original app

Comment: If your "app is designed to intercept other app's api call as an interposer", then you should have root access.

Comment: I think I have found the root cause, actually, android installed the apk without create the corresponding package folder in /data/data which cause the run-as report corrupt installation. but new problem is why android can't create a package folder for my app.